# How to format hour and minutes in date-fns?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

I'm migrating my code from MomentJS to **date-fns** and having the following issue when setting the hour and minutes.

This is my **momentJS** that works just fine:

```
var someDate = moment.utc('2020-07-16T16:35:39.955873Z')) // 2020-07-16T16:35:39.955Z
console.log(someDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY [ at ] LT ')); // 07/16/2020 at 4:35 PM
```

This is my code using **date-fns**:

```
var someTime = zonedTimeToUtc('2020-07-16T16:35:39.955873Z', 'utc'); // 2020-07-16T16:35:39.955Z
console.log(format(new Date(someTime), "MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mm a")); // 07/16/2020 at 10:35 AM
```

so, I want my **date-fns** code to print

> 07/16/2020 at 4:35 PM

but it's printing

> 07/16/2020 at 10:35 AM

Why is that? A simple way to get it to print the date that I want is by removing the "Z" from the value of **someTime** variable (like this: 2020-07-16T16:35:39.955), then it works, but I don't want to remove it manually. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's a [**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-fns-playground-jhmqbn)

Comment: Well, if all else fails, it's pretty simple with vanilla JavaScript Dates: `new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeStyle: "medium",dateStyle: "short"}).replace(',',' at')` - produces your output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `utcToZonedTime()`

To change the displayed date/time returned from format(), you must use either:

- `utcToZonedTime`: when you want to know what the local date is in another timezone
- `zonedTimeToUtc`: when you want to know what a date in another timezone is in the local timezone

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-fns-playground-72kvcp)**